# Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.04 Dual Boot error, UEFI system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

First - yes, there are a bunch of similar questions. Trust me, if any of them had fixed this, I wouldn't be here.

Alright. So I built my own PC, installed Windows 7 on it. I've been wanting to install Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot (first Linux install for me, though I've used it a little otherwise). I downloaded the ISO (64-bit), burned to a flash drive using Rufus. When trying to boot from it, I can get to the grub installer, can edit boot options (I've been removing quiet-splash to see any errors) but every time (both using flash drive, and later a CD) get the same error. Error message is similar to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119173 - freeze at ata2: hard resetting link.

-Using nomodeset as part of boot options in grub
-(Per the linked thread) Asmedia ports disabled
-UEFI enabled
-Tried burning in both MBR and GTP, just in case one happened to work while the other didn't. No luck.
-Secure boot disabled

I created a partition for it already, so it'll have space if it can ever get past the errors. Would very much appreciate any advice, ideas to try, voodoo, and the like.